# Avoiding Jsps or any other templating

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I would like to avoid all templating logic in my web application. I would prefer to: 
1. Pass a single json string to the page through a request attribute on page load
2. No jsp stuff other than this
3. Load the Js object from json and fill-in-the-blanks on the page using js 
4. On user actions update the js model object
5. Once done send the js model object as json

The idea is to do templating also in Js from the json received on form load.

This way every jsp in the application would deal with only a single java object.. A String containing json.

This allows me to think of the whole page like almost a single object-oriented js/html component.

Are there disadvantages to this?

Comment: "Fill-in-the-blanks" *screams* templating.  Unless you're trying to create a RESTful application, what are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: In many pages, half the fields are filled with jsp tags and many are filled after ajax call based on previous fields selection. I want to reduce mixup and do everything in js... Both page load and ajax data can be json. Set values of all  fields using js.